# Bootstrap columns aren't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new at this and am attempting to place two photographs side-by-side in a bootstrap row, but the columns don't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance for any help!

```
<div class="row" style="width: 100%">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <img src="https://heavyeditorial.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/david-joseph.jpg?quality=65&strip=all&strip=all/200x200" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="David Joseph">
    <p class="caption">David Joseph was unarmed when he was fatally shot by Austin police. <em>Photo credit: APD</em></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <img src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.2523996.1454945162!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/article_400/observer9n-3-web.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Antronie Scott">
  <p class="caption">San Antonio police fatally shot Antronie Scott, who was also unarmed. <em>Photo credit: SAPD</em></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is you closing div tag for row and why are you using width:100%?

Comment: add jsfiddle, easier for us to edit your code :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=LLL9w4hbrT

Comment: actually, the other set of rows and columns also isn't working elsewhere in my code. is there a common problem that keeps bootstrap from working?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="https://heavyeditorial.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/david-joseph.jpg?quality=65&strip=all&strip=all/200x200" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="David Joseph">
    <p class="caption">David Joseph was unarmed when he was fatally shot by Austin police. <em>Photo credit: APD</em></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <img src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.2523996.1454945162!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/article_400/observer9n-3-web.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Antronie Scott">
  <p c-lass="caption">San Antonio police fatally shot Antronie Scott, who was also unarmed. <em>Photo credit: SAPD</em></p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you are not happy with a 12-col grid, you can customize it to any other value here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Scroll down to "Grid system", change to your needs, scroll full down, compile and download your very own bootstrap ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for what you are trying to do:

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="https://heavyeditorial.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/david-joseph.jpg?quality=65&strip=all&strip=all/200x200" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="David Joseph">
            <p class="caption">David Joseph was unarmed when he was fatally shot by Austin police. <em>Photo credit: APD</em></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.2523996.1454945162!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/article_400/observer9n-3-web.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Antronie Scott">
            <p class="caption">San Antonio police fatally shot Antronie Scott, who was also unarmed. <em>Photo credit: SAPD</em></p></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the same CSS column classes for all the variations.

Your attempt has col-xs-12 listed, change it to col-xs-6.

Basically, each row has a total of 12 columns, and you want them to be divided equally with each div occupying 6 column width in your case.

Comment: I thought I could have it take 12 columns in xs and 6 in the others. Why aren't the pictures changing with changes in the size of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

For the images you need to add class inside the image tag "img-responsive" :)